# Android - Edit Text and Spinner with custom listview adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

I have a problem which thousands of people had in stackoverflow and I feel bad to ask again, but I read all the questions and tried to implement to my case and none of them worked or probably I implemented them wrong.

Here is my question. I have a custom listview which has one spinner and edittext. I dynamically create rows. As you all know edittext messes up, when scrolling so i implemented, the view holder pattern for smooth scrolling, but still my listview can not show properly. Edit texts are still duplicate itself when scrolled. I am also trying to save user input in another class because I have a spinner and edittext together.  My ***listview row layout:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>


<Spinner
    android:layout_width="128dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ListViewSpinner"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:id="@+id/ListViewEditText"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:hint="Enter the CRN"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ListViewSpinner"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ListViewSpinner" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My ***CourseClass.java***

```
public class CourseClass {
private ArrayList<String> course_name;
private String course_crn;


public CourseClass(ArrayList<String> course_name, String course_crn) {
    super();
    this.setCourse_crn(course_crn);
    this.setCourse_name(course_name);
}

public ArrayList<String> getCourse_name() {
    return course_name;
}

public void setCourse_name(ArrayList<String> course_name) {
    this.course_name = course_name;
}

public String getCourse_crn() {
    return course_crn;
}

public void setCourse_crn(String course_crn) {
    this.course_crn = course_crn;
}
}
```

My ***CourseAdapter.java***

```
public class CourseAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CourseClass> {
Context context;

public CourseAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public void add(CourseClass object) {
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public void remove(CourseClass object) {
    super.remove(object);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (row == null) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.courseSpinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewSpinner);
        holder.courseCrn = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewEditText);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {   
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    final CourseClass course = (CourseClass) getItem(position);
    holder.courseCrn.setText(course.getCourse_crn());
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, course.getCourse_name());
    holder.courseSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    return row;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    Spinner courseSpinner;
    EditText courseCrn;
}

}
```

I already read all of the questions and tutorials but i can't still figure out.

**Can you show where the error or can you give me some ideas to solve my problem?**

Comment: chnages:  row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row_layout, parent,false);   now make viewholder class static

Comment: Using a recycler view will be a better option

Comment: Thank you @Divyesh but now it does not duplicate the values but now it completely removes when the edittext goes off screen.Can you guess why it does?

Comment: @RanjanK.M. if i can not make at the end i will try but it should be done with list view right with viewholder performance is nearly should be the same.

Comment: can you post layout screenshot of what happen?

Comment: Here i enter a value to edittext like this http://prnt.sc/e6ucfy .Then i scroll down and return the top again and it's just like newly created http://prnt.sc/e6uckb

Comment: you can use TextView and open Input Dialog while click on TextView that is best way to take input in Listview.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi so should i make my editext to textview and make input dialog for textviews ?

Comment: Yes , Because its very difficult to hold focus   of  current clicked EditText in ListView.,Its better to take input from dialog and put value back to Data List and notify() Adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You are not updating the course object after editing the `courseCrn`.
Change your `getView()` method in `CourseAdapter` class.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_row_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.courseSpinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewSpinner);
        holder.courseCrn = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.ListViewEditText);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    final CourseClass course = (CourseClass) getItem(position);
    holder.courseCrn.setText(course.getCourse_crn());
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, course.getCourse_name());
    holder.courseSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    holder.courseCrn.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            course.setCourse_crn(s.toString());
        }
    });
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you i added this now but it still removes the field when it disappered from screen.Still the same problem continues.Do you have any thought why it could be ?

Comment: @Alperen please check this code on github. Here is the github project link [link]https://github.com/SanjayKushwah0601/SpinnerWithEditText

Comment: my code is exactly same that you give but i am writing something to edittext when i scroll down it disappears.Not working but thank you for your help.I appreciate that

Comment: did you test it on the emulator cause it is not still does not working for me :(

Comment: It still not working but thank you my friend i will change my approach to the layout and change from listview i couldn't solve the problem.